# Passing multiple parameters in ThreadPoolExecutor.map()

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code:

```
import concurrent.futures 

def worker(item, truefalse):
    print(item, truefalse)
    return item

processed = []
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
    for res in pool.map(worker, [1,2,3], False):
        processed.append(res)
```

Yields an exception: `TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration`

I also tried: `for res in pool.map(worker, ([1,2,3], False)):`

Which yields: `TypeError: worker() missing 1 required positional argument: 'truefalse'`

How does one pass multiple arguments to the function in calling `ThreadPoolExecutor.map()`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to map on? [(1, False), (2, False), (3, False)] or [([1,2,3], false)] ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're trying to call the worker function with `1, False`, then `2, False`, then `3, False`, you need to extend your single `False` to an iterable of `False`s at least as long as the other iterable. Two approaches that work:

1. Multiply a sequence:

   ```
   for res in pool.map(worker, [1,2,3], [False] * 3):
   ```
2. Use `itertools.repeat` to make it as long as needed (`map` will stop when the shortest iterable is exhausted). Add `from itertools import repeat` to the top of the file, then use:

   ```
   for res in pool.map(worker, [1,2,3], repeat(False)):
   ```

For the record, this is also how you'd do this with regular `map`, not just `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: Very nice on the itertools approach. itertools is so useful and it's clean and readable.